# Update hangs code -- Python MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, mysql-connector, freeze

So I'm trying to update a table and for somereason this code decides to freeze when it goes to execute.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                              host='y u so interested',
                              database='discord')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

print ("Start")

update = ("UPDATE admin_daily_playtime_crp1 "
        "SET DiscordName = %s "
        "WHERE SteamName = %s ")
values = ("true", "Modern Mo")
cursor.execute(update, values)
cnx.commit()

print ("done")
```

Table setup:
https://gyazo.com/dde9475d33056b26c04d564e3e8f7349

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider updating your table to include the proper datatypes of each of the columns inside. I changed your snipet to include functions for organization. Call the function discordName(Discord Name, Steam Name) and it should update the information. I tested this on my own database and it worked fine.

```
import mysql.connector



def connection():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='',database='discord')

    return connection

def discordName(discordName, steamName):
    con = connection()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    print ("Start")
    update = "UPDATE `admin_daily_playtime_crp1` SET `DiscordName` = %s WHERE `SteamName` = %s"
    cursor.execute(update, (discordName, steamName))
    print (cursor.rowcount, "record(s) affected!")
    con.commit()
```

Just ask if you have more questions!
Here is an image of the new table I used https://gyazo.com/58dfd93e68ab4d452c896918f8ac2c8a

Comment: I dont understand, somehow it does not hang anymore. Though your code does work, so thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Probably database connection issues or something. Also try to make variables names obvious to what they do that way its easier for others to read the code without having to try and translate it. Not that you're code was bad, but I image the more you write the harder it would be to understand.

Comment: still freezing in my case without any traceback. -1